# Unexpected Keyword when I Pass Url Parameter

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a view called 'Teams' that loops through different NBA teams in a dictionary and shows their name and logo. When the user clicks on one of these logos, I want them to be taken to the 'TeamDetailView'. This should carry over the chosen team's city/name/logo, and I can see this information being passed in the URL. When I attempt to load the team's individual page, though, it gives me a type error and says that

```
TeamDetailView() got an unexpected keyword argument 'city'
```

In the local vars section, it shows my key/value pairs being passed correctly. How can I access these parameters on the team page and correct this error?

```
callback_kwargs {'city': 'Atlanta', 'logo': 'atlanta-logo.png', 'name': 'Hawks'}
```

Here is my view:

```
def TeamDetailView(request): 

    return render(request, 'bandwagon/team.html/')
```

Here is my URL:

```
    path('team/<str:city>/<str:name>/<str:logo>/', views.TeamDetailView, name='bandwagon-team'),
```

Here is my Template for the Teams List:

```
{% for key, value in teams.items %}
    <a class="stream-list" href="{% url 'bandwagon-team' value.city value.name value.logo %}">
        <img class="stream-img" alt="The Logo for the {{ value.city }} {{ value.name }}" src="../../../media/logos/{{ value.logo }}">
        <p class="name">{{value.city }} {{value.name}}</p>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my Template for the Individual Team Page, which is quite basic for now until I get these parameters passed correctly:

```
{% extends 'bandwagon/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 class="article-title">Team</h1>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating your TeamDetailView function to accept the url parameters? Something like -

```
def TeamDetailView(request, city, name, logo): 

    return render(request, 'bandwagon/team.html/')
```

Comment: Thank you! That did work, I don't know how I missed that lack of params before!

Answer (score 0):

As they've tell you before you're not extracting the data from the path, you're just rendering the HTML without any context:

To solve this I would get the Team filtered by the data you're getting of the path, for example:

```
def TeamDetailView(request, city, name, logo):

   Result = Your_Model.objects.all().filter(Q(City=city, Name=name, Logo=logo))
   return render(request, 'bandwagon/team.html', {'Teams': Result})
```

And then in your template you could do something like:

```
 {% for Team in Teams %}

    # What you want to achieve

 {% endfor %}
```